# Clickable Images for Python

Tags: python, image, pygame, clickable-image

I'm an entry level python coder looking to create a Guess Who styled game. At university, I've yet to learn how to import images and bind them to fixed places on a screen (resembling the game board). Is there any way to click on a specific image and have an onClickEvent to occur, where that specific character(image) is chosen.
The majority of my coding abilities are in python, but I am skeptical if this is the best possible language to do a project like this in.

Answer (score 14):

Every GUI has `Button` widget which is clickable and (mostly) can display image.

But mostly in GUI you can assign click event to every object ie. `Label` with `Image`.

ie. Tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def on_click(event=None):
    # `command=` calls function without argument
    # `bind` calls function with one argument
    print("image clicked")

# --- main ---
    
# init    
root = tk.Tk()

# load image
image = Image.open("image.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

# label with image
l = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
l.pack()

# bind click event to image
l.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)

# button with image binded to the same function 
b = tk.Button(root, image=photo, command=on_click)
b.pack()

# button with text closing window
b = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()
    
# "start the engine"
root.mainloop()
```

Graphic modules like `PyGame` can display image too, and have click event but sometimes you have to check manually if you clicked in area with image (and you have to create `mainloop` manually)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say TkInter is your best bet. A little bit cumbersome at first but it's good for beginners. You should be able to make a nice Graphical User Interface with it which will open a window that holds your pictures, menus, buttons, etc...

Take a look at useful docs and examples [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).

If Python is not a requirement, I too would also recommend JS, HTML and CSS (you'll have to use all three together. Sounds scarier than it is :P)